# How to automatically delete emails from gmail server?

Tags: gmail, imap

I am using Gmail-managed personal domain email account through Outlook. 
I am having the problem of limited server space. There is limited server space for emails on Gmail. I want to use IMAP for my mails so how can I manage my server space?
Is there a setting by which after a particular number of days, emails get automatically deleted from the server but a local copy remains on Outlook?
If that is not possible with IMAP (I cannot use POP because I want my mails to be synced), can all mails be automatically deleted after say 45 days?

Comment: I use this at our work place: http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-auto-purge/27605/

Answer (score 0):

You can configure "AutoArchive" in Outlook settings. It will "save" your mails in a local .pst file and remove it frome Gmail server.

Try it first with a short period of time (it could take a while, depending of your Internet connection & PC performance).

Good luck!